# phpstormの設定で設定した内容が起動のたびにクリアされます

Tags: phpstorm

phpstormのsettingで設定したサーバーの設定がphpstormを再起動するたびにクリアされてしまいます。解消方法などをご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけるとありがたいです。なお、設定画面を保存するときに下記のようなエラーが出ております。
●設定画面保存時のエラー
[image: 設定画面保存時のエラー]

●設定画面
[image: phpstorm再起動後の設定]

●再起動後の設定画面
[image: 再起動後の設定画面]

Comment: windows版なら、管理者権限で実行し設定保存がエラー無く出来きるならコンフィグファイルのパーミッションを適切に与えれば直るかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実はconfigのパーミッションは変更してみたのですが、同じでした。

Answer (score 0):

その設定は、プロジェクトの設定として保存されます。
スクリーンショットを見ると、A:¥.idea¥が保存先になりますが、そこは書き込み可能な場所でしょうか？
（ドライブレターがA:なのが珍しいと思ったので）

Comment: Aドライブですが、仮想環境にネットワークドライブを割り当てている分になります。そちらは、windowsから書き込み可能にしております。

Comment: ならためしに、Cドライブにフォルダ作ってそこを指定してみればどうでしょう たんにそのネットワークドライブへの書き込みが失敗してるように見えますが